# add_lvalue_reference implementation example

Tags: c++, c++11, std

When looking for `std::add_lvalue_reference` on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_reference), one can see the following implementation example:

```cpp
namespace detail {

template <class T>
struct type_identity { using type = T; }; // or use std::type_identity (since C++20)

template <class T>
auto try_add_lvalue_reference(int) -> type_identity<T&>;
template <class T>
auto try_add_lvalue_reference(...) -> type_identity<T>;

} // namespace detail

template <class T>
struct add_lvalue_reference : decltype(detail::try_add_lvalue_reference<T>(0)) {};
```

Why is the second `try_add_lvalue_reference` needed and in which cases would it be called in place of the first one?

Comment: Not quite an answer, but I think this is playing with the overload priority, so that the first `try_add_lvalue_reference` will be preferred when adding a reference is necessary. Note that the libc++ implementation is [somewhat different](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/release_90/include/type_traits#L1134).

Comment: I think it only looks different on the surface. It uses [a similar set](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/release_90/include/type_traits#L1071) of functions hidden behind the implementation.

Comment: Right you are...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second overload takes care of the "Otherwise" condition in the definition given on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_reference):

> 1) If T is a function type that has no cv- or ref- qualifier or an object type, provides a member typedef type which is T&. If T is an rvalue reference to some type U, then type is U&. Otherwise, type is T.

Consider for example:

```
using T = void() const; // Function type with const qualifier
using U = add_lvalue_reference<T>::type;
```

According to the definition we should have `U == T`, but if we don't have the second template overload, then this code will cause a compile-time error:

It is impossible to form references to cv- or ref-qualified function types and therefore the first template overload of `try_add_lvalue_reference` is SFINAE'ed out.

If there is only that overload the call `detail::try_add_lvalue_reference<T>(0)` hard-fails because there is no viable overload.

The second overload does not try to form a reference to the const-qualified function type and therefore is always viable and will be chosen if the first one is not, returning the type itself.

The `int` and `...` parameters make sure that both overloads are callable with an `int` argument and the `...` has the additional benefit, that it always has lower priority in overload resolution. So if both template overloads are viable, the first one will be chosen to provide the type with lvalue reference added where possible.

Comment: I completely overlooked function types when trying to derive the behavior of the `try_add_lvalue_reference` helper function. This makes it clearer.